# typedef struct and declaring a structure variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

Currently I'm working on an iOS application, in which I'm using structure for storing some data.

I declared an structure like:

```
typedef struct Message
{
    int    messageType;
    char   *data;
    int    length;
} Message;
```

But when I need to declare a variable I accidentally wrote like:

```
struct Message *myMessage = NULL;
```

This is working fine, no issues.

My question is why this line not displaying any issues ?

Both :

```
struct Message *myMessage = NULL;
```

and

```
Message *myMessage = NULL;
```

Working correctly. Is this correct behavior of `typedef` ? Why it won't display any error when I used `struct Message` ?

Comment: Its a standard practice with naming conventions that if you have 'typedef'ed structure, then the name should be followed by '_t'. For example, it should be Message_t. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.

The name following the keyword `struct`, called the "struct tag", is not in the same "name space" as the `typedef` alias name. That's why they're not colliding and generating some kind of error.

That said, you should remove the tag from your declaration, and just make it:

```
typedef struct
{
    int    messageType;
    char   *data;
    int    length;
} Message;
```

No point in introducing names that are not needed, and that would also protect you from this kind of confusion since there would be no name to write `struct` before.

Comment: There could be a point in naming the struct tag the same as the typedef though, in the case you have self-referencing structs, like for example a node in a linked list: `typedef struct node { node* next; int data; } node;`. This make it possible to link such a struct, as the struct tag is visible to the struct declaration itself, but the typedef name is not.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is expected.  `struct Message` is a type, and your typedef has created `Message` as an alias for it.  You can use either when declaring variables.

Answer (score 2):

The above declares both `struct Message` and its "alias" as `Message`. Both is fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior of `typedef`.

Answer (score 0):

May be that is why, We have been suggested to follow the naming convention for typedef as I said above.

```
struct Message {  
    int messageType;  
    char *data;  
    int length;  
}Message_t;
```

Above is the good practice to declare `struct` with their `typedef`. And in embedded you will usually find it to be, `Message_Type`.